# Complex forms with Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

is there any way to do complex forms with validation, for example:

Form with radio button with 2 choices A and B and field1,field2 and field3 required IF choice A is selected, and field4, field5 and field6 required IF choice B is selected?

Comment: Yes, you can use Callback constraints, or FormEvents on POST_SUBMIT to operates supplementary validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to generate client side control in real time (insert **required="required"** when necessary), I think the easiest way is to handle it with some Javascript event.

A FormEvent will not be sufficient to manage the user change (if the first radio change from A to B in your example).

For the "real" validation stuff, the best practice is to create your own **class validator**.

You can learn more about it here :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator

Best regards.

Comment: Symfony only handle server-side validation (something that you must implement always). Client validation made in JS is only for a better UX and/or UI

Comment: I am agree, that is why i oriented him to a symfony class validator (js is a bonus indeed ;) )

Comment: Thank you. That's what I need. I hoped to something more "ready" and built-in, but that's ok. :)